# Unable to format, or access data contents of i-Ball pen drive

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

Every time I try to access the contents of my pen drive in any PC I see a dialog box with the following error message:

> Disk is not formatted

I then give it the order to format the pen drive. However, it's not successful and gives me a dialog box with this error:

> Windows was unable to complete the format

After I press OK it then give me this message:

> Disk is not formatted.

Then I try to format via DOS prompt and use this command:

```
format i:/q/fs:fat32
```

But nothing happens to the disk.

How can I access the data from my pen drive?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the power of Ubuntu to solve your problem.

- Create an [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)
- Boot into Ubuntu (you do not have to install Ubuntu)
- Plug in your USB drive
- Use the built-in disk utility to partition your drive

Other than that, I'd say your USB drive is dead.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I access the data from my pen drive?

Restore the data from your regular backup to another USB drive.